# Sort Image with latest modified on top

Tags: php, image, sorting, timthumb

I am using the following code from Timthumb to built an thumb gallery on my page from a directory.
However, I would like to have my image sort so that the latest image is on top.
I've try to implement some codes I found on this website, but with no luck.
Can anyone help? You can ignore all the stuff with regex.

```
   <?php
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    $ignore = Array(".", "..", ".DS_Store", "index.php");
    foreach($images as $curimg){
        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
            echo "<li><img src=\"img.php?src=$dirname$curimg&w=500&zc=1&q=50\" alt='' style=\"width:100%;\" /></li>\n ";
        }
    }               
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: What problems are you having? Are images displaying, but are not sorted, or something else?

Comment: I would use filetime and push the file names (after comparing them) into an array (that acts like a stack).After that, do a foreach on that array and print the html.

Comment: It is currently displaying with oldest image on top. I would like to reverse the order so newest image are at the top. I'm not very good with codes. How do I use the filetime parameter?